# Sonata Admin: why the password field is not encrypted?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, encryption, sonata-admin

Using Symfony2, Sonata Admin and mongodb, the application save the fields but the password is not encrypted.

The CRUD work very fine saving the User fields on database, the problem is when loggin i got "Bad Credentials", and when i see the database the password is not encrypted.

I am not using UserBundle,FOSUserBundle.

1. UserAdmin.php

   ```
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
   {
       $formMapper
       ->add('names', null, array('label' => 'Nombres','required' => true))
       ->add('surnames', null, array('label' => 'Apellidos'))
       ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Email','required' => true))
       ->add('password', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password',
                           'first_options' => array('label' => 'Contraseña'),
                           'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repita la contraseña'),
                           'invalid_message' => 'Las contraseñas no coinciden'
                           ))
       ->add('birthday','date', array('label' => 'Fecha de Nacimiento',
                     'years' => range(date('y'),date('Y')-90),
                     'format' => 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
                     ));
   }
   ```
2. security.yml

   ```
   security:
       encoders:
       Bluetton\DispatcherBundle\Document\User:
         algorithm: sha512
         encode-as-base64: true
         iterations: 10

       role_hierarchy:
       ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
       ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

       providers:
       dispatcherdb:
           mongodb: { class: Bluetton\DispatcherBundle\Document\User, property: email }

       firewalls:
       main:
           pattern: /.*
           provider: dispatcherdb
           form_login:
           login_path: /login
           check_path: /login_check
           remember_me: true
           logout:
           path: /logout
           target: /
           remember_me:
           key: MiClaveSegura
           lifetime: 1800
           path: /.*
           domain: ~
           security: true
           anonymous: true
       access_control:
       - { path: /setup, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: /user, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } #ROLE_USER } #
       - { path: /.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
   ```
3. SecurityController.php

   ```
   class SecurityController extends Controller
   {
       public function loginAction()
       {
           $request = $this->getRequest();
           $session = $request->getSession();

           // get the login error if there is one
           if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
               $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
           } else {
               $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
           }

           return $this->render('DispatcherBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
               // last username entered by the user
               'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
               'error'         => $error,
           ));
       }
       public function indexAction()
       {
           $user = new User();

           $validator = $this->get('validator');
           $errors = $validator->validate($user);

           if (count($errors) > 0) {

               $errorsString = (string) $errors;

               return new Response($errorsString);
           }

           return new Response('El usuario es valido!');
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem overriding the functions preUpdate() and prePersist() on UserAdmin class

```
            public function preUpdate($object) {
                $uniqid = $this->getRequest()->query->get('uniqid');
                $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 10);
                $formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get($uniqid);
                if(array_key_exists('password', $formData) && $formData['password'] !== null && strlen($formData['password']['first' ]) > 0) {
                    $object->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($formData['password']['first' ],$object->getSalt()));
                }
            }

            public function prePersist($object) {
                $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 10);
                $uniqid = $this->getRequest()->query->get('uniqid');
                $formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get($uniqid);
                if(array_key_exists('password', $formData) && $formData['password'] !== null && strlen($formData['password']['first' ]) > 0) {
                    $object->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($formData['password']['first' ],$object->getSalt()));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use hooks as described [there](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html) (your case for sure)
2. you need to change field declaration to something like that (use plainPassword instead of password)

```
    ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ))
```